# Why do I get everything after the first run in Jetpack Joyride?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

After my first run, I was looking around in the shop, and suddenly, I got every gadget, jetpack, all the clothes, etc. When I re-installed the game, the same thing happens.

Comment: It was probably just a glitch

Comment: And why would you complain about it??!!

Comment: What do you mean, it says that you unlcked everything or does it say that you bought everything? If it says you unlocked everything than it is fine. But if it says you bought everything.. Than that's a glitch, ENJOY IT! :D

Answer (score 1):

If these are just showing up as unlocked but not purchased then that would be normal. If however you can use any of these without making the relevant amount of progression, then it is possible that you have downloaded a 'cracked' or 'modded' version of the game where everything is unlocked.

Alternatively, if you have played before and are logged in, even though you have re-installed the game it could be logging back into your account and showing your previous progression.